# Insert Summary not showing formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to get the sum of total days calculated from date range. The only condition is if the previous end date is equals to the running record begin date, i don't need to count that day again. I have written below function but I could not see it neither in Insert Summary nor in Running Total field.

After checking number of solutions on internet it seems that the total only works on number field and not on constants or on other variable type. I write the below function considering all solutions i have seen so far but it didn't worked out.

```
whileprintingrecords;
Global numbervar value :=0;
Datevar prevdate := Previous({MainReport_24172.ENDDATE});
if {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE}= DateValue (9990,12 ,31 ) then
   value := value + CurrentDate - {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE}+1
else if prevdate = {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE} then
    value := value + {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE} - {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE}
else
   value := value + {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE} - {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE} + 1
```

01.09.2019 02.09.2019  2
02.09.2019 04.09.2019  2
04.09.2019 04.09.2019  0

It should print total number of days - 4

Comment: Try to remove "Global" from variable declarion and check if the formula shows up in summary or running total field. If it still does not show up, try to remove whileprintingrecords and try again. Since you use "previous", maybe it will work only for running total field, but i am not sure.

Comment: I did some testes and confirmed that "whileprintingrecords" and "previous" are preventing the formula to show up in the summary operation.

Comment: yes, previous is the culprit but any way/solution to compare/check previous end date and running record begin date. To more clarify it why it is required - we are calculating length of stay in various rooms of hospital with date range and trying to print the total days spent in hospital. So if the patient is moved from one room/ward to another we cannot count the same date again. I am not aware of any other function on logic to achieve this? Any idea?

Comment: Use variables. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula to initiate global vars. Put the formula in report header. Suppress it.

```
Global numbervar value :=0;
Global DateTimevar prevdate := DateValue (9990,12 ,31 );
```

Then create another formula. Here is the slightly changed version of your original formula:

```
//do not set a value here! it just means the vars are being reused
Global numbervar value;
Global DateTimevar prevdate;

if {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE}= DateValue (9990,12 ,31 ) then
   value := value + DATEDIFF("d", {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE}, CurrentDate)+1 //assuming BEGINDATE always <= CurrentDate
else if prevdate = {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE} then
    value := value + DATEDIFF("d", {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE}, {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE})
else
   value := value + DATEDIFF("d", {MainReport_24172.BEGINDATE}, {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE}) + 1;
prevdate := {MainReport_24172.ENDDATE}; //for the next iteration
value;
```

This way, if you put the second formula in report footer, it will print the total of days.

If you need to group by some criteria, i believe you will have to reset the global vars in the group header. So, the first formula would go there. And the second formula would be in the group footer.

Comment: Thanks heringer,  as you have suggested, I have put the global variable in group header so that they get reinitialized for second group but it is still adding the previous total of earlier group with the total of second group, so on and so forth. Are we (or Am I) doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work. May you show some screenshots of your design?